# C# Counter increase only if textbox not blank

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, counter

I am working on a homework assignment that is a guessing game. The user is trying to guess a number 0-100. I am really new to C# and this is only my second windows form. I am trying to make a button event that checks if my text box is blank. if it is not blank I need it to add to a counter, once the user guesses the correct number a window is supposed to pop up saying something like "it took you *this many* tries!". "this many" being my counter... I hope this makes sense. At some point I also need to make sure that the user is only entering numbers. I'm just trying to figure out this counter right now... Here is my code so far. There is some code commented off. I am totally lost.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Generates random number for game
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int rndNumber = rnd.Next(101);
    this.number.Text = rndNumber.ToString();
}

//Makes sure user only enters numbers 0-100
private void guess_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

//does this when evaluate button is clicked
private void evaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //counter for the number of guesses
    int guessNumber;
    guessNumber = 0;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.guess.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Must enter a number 0-100 to play");

        // while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.guess.Text))
            // {
            // guessNumber++;
            // }
    }
    else
    {
        guessNumber++;
        MessageBox.Show(guessNumber.ToString());
    }            
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm late, Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int guessNumber;
    int rndNumber;
    int userNumber;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Generates random number for game
        Random rnd = new Random();
        rndNumber = rnd.Next(101);
        this.number.Text = rndNumber.ToString();

    }


    //does this when evaluate button is clicked        
    private void evaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //counter for the number of guesses



        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.guess.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Must enter a number 0-100 to play");

            // while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.guess.Text))
            // {
            // guessNumber++;
            // }
        }
        else
        {
            guessNumber++;
            userNumber = Convert.ToInt32(guess.Text);
            if (userNumber == rndNumber)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("you took these many guesses = "+guessNumber.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Guess Try Again!!!");
            }

        }
    }

    //Makes sure user only enters numbers 0-100
    private void guess_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userInput=Convert.ToInt32(guess.Text);
        if (!(userInput > 0 && userInput <= 100))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("enter number between 1 and 100");
            guess.Text = userInput.ToString().Substring(0, userInput.ToString().Length - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your evaluate_Click method looks fine.  If the text box is empty tell them to put in a value.  In the else - before increment the counter - check if they put in the right value first.  If they did not put in the right value - increment the counter.

You need to put the "counter" at the class (form) level.  If you put it in the event like that - it will have localscope and will be reset to 0 everytime the event is called.  Declare the "guessNumber" variable at the class level and increment it in the event and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

Have a variable whose scope is outside of the evaluate method. Perhaps above the `public Form1()` line. This way it is defined in the local scope of the class and not just the methd so that all methods can access it.

Upon starting the evaluate method, increment the counter straight away before any further processing. So your code will look something like:

```
private void evaluate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    if (!string.isEmptyOrNull(this.guess.text))
    {
         if (rndNumber == Int32.Parse(this.guess.text))
             //Display you are correct
         else
             //Display guess again
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For only numbers in your textbox you can try this code on your TextBox KeyPress event

```
private void guess_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled=!(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar));
   //This will only allow numeric values in TextBox
}
```